# How can I match values from first row of array with values from first column to create a json?

Tags: python, json

I have a list of lists in python that has data like this:

```
Metric, Person1, Person2, Person3, Person4, ...
Sex|Male, 0.50,  0.75,    0.35,     0.80, ...
Sex|Female, 0,50, 0.25,   0.65,     0.20, ....
Age| 18-24, 0.25,  0.20,   0.15,     0.17, ...
```

I would like to create a JSON with the following structure:

```
 data = [{Person1:[{Sex|Male:0.50},  {Sex|Female:0.50}, {Age|18-24:0.25}]}, {Person2:[{Sex|Male:0.75},{Sex|Female:0.25}, {Age|18-24:0.20}]}, ...]
```

How can I match these values using Python?

Comment: Usually Person1, Person2, .. are not columns, but lines. Did you verify that ?

Comment: Try to show is in form of list of a list. Is it [[Metric, Person1, Person2, Person3, Person4,]..] or [[Metric,Sex|Male,Sex|Female,Age]..]. I mean, Are you taking it horozantally or vertically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you say, you have a list of lists, i.e.

```
data = [
    ['Metric', 'Person1', 'Person2', 'Person3', 'Person4'],
    ['Sex|Male', 0.5, 0.75, 0.35, 0.8],
    ['Sex|Female', 0, 50, 0.25, 0.65, 0.2],
    ['Age| 18-24', 0.25, 0.2, 0.15, 0.17],
]
```

the following will produce the required output:

```
>>> l = zip(*data)    # swap rows and columns - it's easier to work this way
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(l)
[('Metric', 'Sex|Male', 'Sex|Female', 'Age| 18-24'),
 ('Person1', 0.5, 0, 0.25),
 ('Person2', 0.75, 50, 0.2),
 ('Person3', 0.35, 0.25, 0.15),
 ('Person4', 0.8, 0.65, 0.17)]

>>> result = []
>>> for row in l[1:]:
...     result.append({row[0] : [{l[0][i] : row[i]} for i in range(1, len(row))]})

>>> pprint(result)
[{'Person1': [{'Sex|Male': 0.5}, {'Sex|Female': 0}, {'Age| 18-24': 0.25}]},
 {'Person2': [{'Sex|Male': 0.75}, {'Sex|Female': 50}, {'Age| 18-24': 0.2}]},
 {'Person3': [{'Sex|Male': 0.35}, {'Sex|Female': 0.25}, {'Age| 18-24': 0.15}]},
 {'Person4': [{'Sex|Male': 0.8}, {'Sex|Female': 0.65}, {'Age| 18-24': 0.17}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of lists in Python, right?

Let the list be data, and the number of columns is Nc, number of rows is Nr.

List comprehension way:

```
dict = {data[i][0]:[{data[j][0]:data[j][i]} for j in range(1,Nr)] for i in range(1,Nc)}
```

or by normal for loop:

```
for i in range(1,Nc):
  dict[data[i][0]] = []
  for j in range(1,Nr):
    dict.append({data[j][0]:data[j][i]})
```

Test:

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> dd = {l[0][i]:[{l[j][0]:l[j][i]} for j in range(1,3)] for i in range(1,3)}
>>> dd
{2: [{4: 5}, {7: 8}], 3: [{4: 6}, {7: 9}]}
```